# Why isn't jQuery working in this question's code snippet?

Tags: bug

This question's code initially didn't use the jQuery script tag. I proved the code was working correctly in jsfiddle, except that it lacked jQuery.

[Trigger CSS transition with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016258/trigger-css-transition-with-javascript)

Then the user included the jQuery script tag in the code snippet, but it still wouldn't work.

Anyone knows why? Is this a code snippet bug?

Comment: The only thing tags do is syntax highlighting...

Comment: but then how can the code be run ?

Comment: You can use Stack Snippets on Meta, for example. It's not magic... What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Well basically 3 things: 1 - if it just highlight things how come there is a working "run code snippet" button ? 2 - if it runs how it didn't recognize script tag with jquery link so that I can run jquery code in it ? 3 - if it recognizes jquery, and I think it recognizes cause I have seen examples of this, why the question code won't recognize jquery ?

Comment: The "Run Code Snippet" thing is completely different feature than the syntax highlighter and tag system. (Plenty of users are stupid and put Android code in there anyway.) I'm not a jQuery expert so I can't really tell you *why* the code wasn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Stack Overflow or code snippets. You fixed the problem by adding a newer version of jQuery.

[jQuery SVG, why can't I addClass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass)

Regarding your suggested edit, please don't edit questions to *fix* them. That completely defeats the purpose of this site.

Comment: Welll but it's still not working to me

Comment: Put a newer version and it worked. Thanks